# separate number digits postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, split, numbers

i'm trying to find an sql function that can split a number into separate digits.
ex. num=78912346
split_num(num)={7,8,9,1,2,3,4,6}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string_to_array with a `null` delimiter

```
select string_to_array(78912346::text, null)
```